# Rewrite the first line in a text file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to rewrite the first line in a text-file in a function in PowerShell.
This is my code but it doesn't work.

```
$deel = Get-Content E:\Examen\Nieuw\deel.txt

function lijnHerschrijven($naam1, $naam2) {
    ($deel) | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "$naam1", "$naam2"} |
        Set-Content E:\Examen\Nieuw\deel.txt
}
lijnHerschrijven("Deel 1", "Deel 2")
```

So the file has 1 line in it → "Deel 1", and when I call the function it has to replace "Deel 1" into "Deel 2". But the file keeps saying "Deel 1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you call your function actually with an array of 2 strings instead of passing two arguments. Change your last line to

```
lijnHerschrijven "Deel 1" "Deel 2"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function Rename-Something
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param
  (
    [String]
    $Path,

    [String]
    $Naam1,

    [String]
    $naam2
  )

  $File = Get-Content -Path $Path
  $File[0] = $File[0] -replace $naam1, $naam2
  $File | Set-Content -Path $Path
}

Rename-Something -Path yourtextfile -Naam1 deel1 -naam2 deel2
```

function parameters need to be separated by space as shown above.
Note: this function will only replace the first line and nothing else.